# SQL Server : trigger deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, deadlock

There is an `InventoryCategory` table and I have the following trigger attached to that table. The main purpose of trigger is to update the `ProcessQueue` table with `InventoryCategory` `RowID` when someone update or insert or delete a record in `InventoryCategory` table so that I know which records are updated recently and then I need to update other systems.

I have a multi threaded C# application updating `InventoryCategory` and this trigger is causing a deadlock. If I run the it with single thread I don't have any error.

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[tr_InventoryCategory_Queue]
On [dbo].[InventoryCategory]
After Insert, Update, Delete
as
   if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
      return

   -- inserted records need to be either inserted or deleted into the queue
   if exists(select 1 from inserted)
   begin
       -- update existing queue records
       update ProcessQueue
       set ParentTable = 'InventoryCategory', UpdatedTime = getdate()
       from inserted i
       join ProcessQueue p on i.Id = p.RowID 
       where exists (select * from ProcessQueue q
                     where q.RowID = p.RowID and q.ParentTable = 'InventoryCategory')
       and p.ParentTable = 'InventoryCategory'

       -- insert new queue records
       insert into ProcessQueue (ParentTable, RowID)
          select 
              'InventoryCategory', i.id
          from
               inserted i
          where 
               i.ID not in (select q.RowID from ProcessQueue q
                            where q.ParentTable = 'InventoryCategory')
    end

    -- deleted records need to be either inserted or updated into the queue
    if exists(select 1 from deleted)
    begin
        -- update existing queue records
        update ProcessQueue
        set ParentTable = 'InventoryCategory', UpdatedTime = getdate()
        from deleted d
        join ProcessQueue p on d.Id = p.RowID 
        where exists (select * from ProcessQueue q
                      where q.RowID = p.RowID and q.ParentTable = 'InventoryCategory')
        and p.ParentTable = 'InventoryCategory'

        -- insert new queue records
        insert into ProcessQueue (ParentTable, RowID)
           select 
              'InventoryCategory', d.Id
           from
              deleted d
           where 
              d.Id not in (select q.RowID from ProcessQueue q
                           where q.ParentTable = 'InventoryCategory')
     end
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would use with(nolock) with all of the select statements.

Comment: too many actions in trigger. Try optimize you select-statements. try review you bisness logic. For insert and delete operations create two triggers

Comment: Perhaps use a queue approach instead of multithreading?

Comment: Post the execution plan and deadlock graph. Deadlocks can often be fixed by adding indexes or adding pessimistic locking hints. This is never trivial, though. Consider just adding a retry loop (`SqlException.Number == 1205`).